# Why my Render has black outlines?

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Im noob here. I tried to make a sci-fi car but when I render it, its like this(see photo).

I dont want these black lines

[image: render]

Comment: because you turned on "Freestyle" https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally activated *Freestyle* which is a non-photorealistic render engine for drawing line art. It can be deactivated by unchecking the *Freestyle* option in the *Render* tab.

[image: Freestyle option]